# How to grep -v and also exclude the next line after the match?

Tags: text-processing, grep

How to filter out 2 lines for each line matching the grep regex?
this is my minimal test:

```
SomeTestAAAA
EndTest
SomeTestABCD
EndTest
SomeTestDEFG
EndTest
SomeTestAABC
EndTest
SomeTestACDF
EndTest
```

And obviously I tried e.g. `grep -vA 1 SomeTestAA` which doesn't work.

desired output is:

```
SomeTestABCD
EndTest
SomeTestDEFG
EndTest
SomeTestACDF
EndTest
```

Comment: grep -v 'SomeTextAA' | uniq ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use `grep` with `-P` (PCRE) :

```
grep -P -A 1 'SomeTest(?!AA)' file.txt
```

`(?!AA)` is the zero width negative lookahead pattern ensuring that there is no `AA` after `SomeTest`.

Test :

```
$ grep -P -A 1 'SomeTest(?!AA)' file.txt 
SomeTestABCD
EndTest
SomeTestDEFG
EndTest
SomeTestACDF
EndTest
```

Comment: what's the escape character for dots? like Some.Test.AA?

Comment: @Behrooz Escape dots by `\.` so `grep -P -A 1 'SomeTest\.(?!AA)' file.txt` or `grep -P -A 1 'SomeTest(?!\.AA)' file.txt`

Comment: This works in this particular case because in OPs sample lines come in pairs of `SomeTest*\nEndTest` so you are actuallly `grep`ping all lines matching `SomeTest*` but not `SomeTestAA` + one line of context after the match. Add some more lines to the input (e.g add a line `foobar` after each `EndTest` line) then try it again.

Comment: @don_crissti that's true, I already worked around that.

Comment: @Behrooz - care to share with us how you worked around that and maybe answer my comment under your question ?

Comment: @don_crissti I had only a couple lines that were different in the beginning and end of my input. so I handled them manually:D. this was a one-time thing.

Answer (score 9):

You can use GNU `sed`'s `d` command to delete a line, and prefix it with `/pat/,+N` to select lines matching the pattern and the subsequent *N* lines. In your case, *N* = 1 since you only want to delete the single subsequent line after a matching line:

```
sed -e '/SomeTestAAAA/,+1d'
```

Answer (score 6):

Tried with below GNU `sed` command and it worked fine

command

```
sed  '/SomeTestAA/,+1d' filename
```

output

```
SomeTestABCD
EndTest
SomeTestDEFG
EndTest
SomeTestACDF
EndTest
```

Comment: This worked beautifully! I needed to make +1d into +2d to also get rid of annoying whitespace, but otherwise 10/10

Answer (score 5):

Here's a `sed` solution (with `-n` i.e. no auto-printing) that works with arbitrary input:

```
sed -n '/SomeTestAA/!p          # if line doesn't match, print it
: m                             # label m
//{                             # if line matches
$!{                             # and if it's not the last line
n                               # empty pattern space and read in the next line
b m                             # branch to label m (so n is repeated until a
}                               # line that's read in no longer matches) but
}                               # nothing is printed
' infile
```

so with an input like

```
SomeTestAAXX
SomeTestAAYY
+ one line
SomeTestONE
Message body
EndTest
########
SomeTestTWO
something here
EndTest
SomeTestAABC
+ another line
SomeTestTHREE
EndTest
SomeTestAA
+ yet another line
```

running

```
sed -n -e '/SomeTestAA/!p;: m' -e '//{' -e '$!{' -e 'n;b m' -e '}' -e'}' infile
```

outputs

```
SomeTestONE
Message body
EndTest
########
SomeTestTWO
something here
EndTest
SomeTestTHREE
EndTest
```

that is, it removes exactly the lines that `grep -A1 SomeTestAA infile` would select:

```
SomeTestAAXX
SomeTestAAYY
+ one line
--
SomeTestAABC
+ another line
--
SomeTestAA
+ yet another line
```

Comment: Interesting. I didn't realize that `//` matched `/SomeTestAA/`. I thought, in this case, it would have matched the negated expression: `/SomeTestAA/!`.  (+1)

Comment: @Peter.O - thanks ! No, per the specs, an empty _RE_ should always match the last _RE_ used in the last command; the `!` is not part of the _RE_, it's a `sed` thing.

Comment: @Peter.O What do you mean by RE?

Comment: @ConstantFun - _RE_ is short for Regular Expression

Comment: @Peter.O Thanks for clarifying. I feel kind of stupid now. xD

Answer (score 4):

One option is to use `p`erl `c`ompatible `r`egular `e`xpression `grep`:

```
pcregrep -Mv 'SomeTestAA.*\n' file
```

The option `-M` allows pattern to match more then one line.

Comment: @don_crissti Both lines will be removed. OP's specification doesn't cover this case.

Comment: It's quite obvious the OPs sample & question don't cover such cases, I'm just curious to know how this works (I'm not familiar with pcre) because with an odd number of consecutive lines that match, this works (it removes the context line too) and with an even number of consecutive lines that match, it fails (it doesn't remove the context line after).

Comment: Given that (GNU) `grep` already supports PCRE (via the `-P` option), what is the advantage of using `pcregrep`?

Comment: @arielf `grep` doesn't support `-M` option.

Answer (score 3):

Using standard `sed`:

```
$ sed '/SomeTestAA/{ N; d; }' file
SomeTestABCD
EndTest
SomeTestDEFG
EndTest
SomeTestACDF
EndTest
```

The `sed` script parses the input file line by line, and when a line matches the pattern `SomeTestAA`, the two `sed` editing commands `N` and `d` are executed.  The `N` command appends the next line of input to the pattern space (the buffer that `sed` can edit), and the `d` deletes the pattern space and starts the next cycle.

Answer (score 2):

You might have better luck with something that looks at multi-line regions as single records.  There's an `sgrep` which I haven't used much.

There's also awk, where you can set the input record separator, and output record separator, to whatever you like.

```
pat="^SomeTestAA"
awk  'BEGIN{ RS=ORS="\nEndTest\n"} !/'"$pat/" foo
```

Most of the awk program is single-quoted, but I change to double quotes at the end so the `$pat` shell variable can be expanded.

Comment: `awk -vpat="^SomeTestAA" -vRS="\nEndTest\n" 'BEGIN{ ORS=RS } $0 !~ pat' file`