# How to search only 'not-installed' packages in Arch Linux?

Tags: arch-linux, pacman

What flags can one use with `pacman -S` to show only those packages, that aren't yet installed?

Will accept shell script if it can't be done by design. Thx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After first try was the inverse answer, thanks Jeff Schaller. Here's a little script that filters out installed packages and only displays not installed packages.

```
#!/bin/sh

installed=$(pacman -Q | cut -d ' ' -f 1 | tr '\n' '|')
pacman -Ssq | egrep -v \'${installed}\'
```

Comment: "... *aren't* yet installed"

Comment: PLUS: Use `pacman -Ssq | egrep -v \'${installed}\' | egrep -i '<YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME_OR_PART>'` to search only among uninstalled packages. NOTE: `q` flag excludes description. Ref.: https://www.archlinux.org/pacman/pacman.8.html#_query_options_a_id_qo_a

Comment: As egrep is deprecated, I used `pacman -Ssq | grep -E -v  \'${installed}\' ` - and to search you just add it to the first part, no additional piping needed:  `pacman -Ssq pkgname | grep -E -v  \'${installed}\' `   (after setting the installed variable).  To pass this on to pacman for installation, you to add another pipe: `pacman -Ssq xfce4 | grep -E -v  \'${installed}\'  | pacman -S -`

Answer (score 1):

here is a script with 3 different methods, all keeping the one line description. also it lets you do search terms with command line arguments

```
#!/bin/bash
#pacman -Ss "$@" | pcregrep -Mv '.*\[installed.*\n'
#pacman -Ss "$@" | sed -n -e '/\[installed/!p;: m' -e '//{' -e '$!{' -e 'n;b m' -e '}' -e'}'
pacman -Ss "$@" | awk '/\[installed/ { getline; next } 1'
```

example:

```
pacman-search-exclude-installed.sh search terms
```

my research:

[How to grep -v and also exclude the next line after the match?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/226348/how-to-grep-v-and-also-exclude-the-next-line-after-the-match)

[How to `grep -v` and also exclude 'n' lines after the match?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/472503/how-to-grep-v-and-also-exclude-n-lines-after-the-match?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 0):

expanding on @thomas answer here are some ready to go functions you can source and use to achieve OPs question

```
pmig () {
  pacman -Q | grep $1 | cut -d ' ' -f 1 
}

pmrg () {
pacman -Ssq | grep $1
}

pmnig () {
local installed="|$(pmig $1 | tr '\n' '|')"
pmrg $1 | grep -E -v \'${installed}\'
}

pmnigv () {
  pacman -Ss $1 | grep -v "$(pacman -Ss $1 | grep "\[installed\]" -A1 )" | grep -v "\[installed\]" 
}
```

then trying out.

`echo "==installed =="; pmig disk; echo "==in repos=="; pmrg disk; echo "===in repos but not installed==="; pmnig disk`

results in

```
==installed ==
gnome-disk-utility
gptfdisk
udiskie
udisks2
==in repos==
gnome-disk-utility
gptfdisk
plasma-disks
testdisk
udisks2
xfce4-diskperf-plugin
deepin-diskmanager
diskonaut
diskus
haskell-disk-free-space
kdiskmark
udiskie
udisks2-qt5
xdiskusage
yubikey-full-disk-encryption
===in repos but not installed===
plasma-disks
testdisk
xfce4-diskperf-plugin
deepin-diskmanager
diskonaut
diskus
haskell-disk-free-space
kdiskmark
xdiskusage
yubikey-full-disk-encryption
```

an pmnigv is a verbose version

`pmigv disk`

```
extra/cdrdao 1.2.5-1
    Records audio/data CD-Rs in disk-at-once (DAO) mode
extra/filelight 22.12.2-1 (kde-applications kde-utilities)
    View disk usage information
extra/kdf 22.12.2-1 (kde-applications kde-utilities)
    View Disk Usage
extra/libisofs 1.5.4-1
    Library to pack up hard disk files and directories into a ISO 9660 disk image
extra/mtools 1:4.0.42-1
    A collection of utilities to access MS-DOS disks
extra/partitionmanager 22.12.2-1 (kde-applications kde-system)
    A KDE utility that allows you to manage disks, partitions, and file systems
extra/plasma-disks 5.26.5-1 (plasma)
    Monitors S.M.A.R.T. capable devices for imminent failure
extra/qemu-img 7.2.0-3
    QEMU tooling for manipulating disk images
....
```