# How to `grep -v` and also exclude 'n' lines after the match?

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, grep

I've been reading [How to grep -v and also exclude the next line after the match?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/226348/how-to-grep-v-and-also-exclude-the-next-line-after-the-match) and wondering how to exclude the 2 lines, or any number after the match using `sed` or any other practical tools.

```
user@linux:~$ cat -n file.txt 
     1  SomeTestAAAA
     2  Random String
     3  EndTest
     4  SomeTestABCD
     5  Random String
     6  EndTest
     7  SomeTestDEFG
     8  Random String
     9  EndTest
    10  SomeTestAABC
    11  Random String
    12  EndTest
    13  SomeTestACDF
    14  Random String
    15  EndTest
user@linux:~$
```

**1st Question**

I was able to accomplish this using `grep -P` as follows; unfortunately there is unwanted `--` character in the output.

How to remove this?

```
user@linux:~$ grep -P -A 2 'SomeTest(?!AA)' file.txt
SomeTestABCD
Random String
EndTest
SomeTestDEFG
Random String
EndTest
--
SomeTestACDF
Random String
EndTest
user@linux:~$
```

**Question 2**

I've also managed to do this with `awk` as shown in previous answer. However this is only working on this case because of the similar `EndTest` pattern. What if `EndTest` is some random word and doesn't have pattern.

Could we do something similar as `grep -v -A 2 SomeTestAA`? I know this won't work, but the desired output would be similar as follows.

```
user@linux:~$ awk  'BEGIN{ RS=ORS="\nEndTest\n"} !/'"^SomeTestAA/" file.txt 
SomeTestABCD
Random String
EndTest
SomeTestDEFG
Random String
EndTest
SomeTestACDF
Random String
EndTest
user@linux:~$
```

Comment: For Q1, see if your grep supports a `--no-group-separator` option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using GNU `sed`:

```
$ sed '/AA/,+2d' <file
SomeTestABCD
String
EndTest
SomeTestDEFG
String
EndTest
SomeTestACDF
String
EndTest
```

The GNU `sed` script finds lines containing the string `AA` and then deletes that line and the following two lines from the input.  The `+2` relative addressing is a GNU `sed` extension to standard `sed`.

Using standard `sed`, deleting two lines:

```
sed -n '/AA/{n;n;d;}; p' <file
```

This uses `sed` without implicitly outputting every line of input (with `-n`). When the `AA` pattern is matched, the next two lines are explicitly read and deleted.  All lines that don't trigger the pattern will be printed.

With standard `sed`, deleting to the `EndTest` line:

```
sed '/AA/,/^EndTest$/d' <file
```

This deletes all lines from the lines that contains the string `AA` to the immediately following line that matches the pattern `^EndTest$`.

---

Using `awk` to ignore two lines after matching `AA`:

```
awk '/AA/ { getline; getline; next } 1' <file
```

Using `awk` in the same way as the last `sed` variation:

```
awk '/AA/,/^EndTest$/ { next } 1' <file
```

Comment: with sed : sed '/AA/!b;N;N;d' or with awk : awk '/AA/{f=3}f{f--;next}1'

Comment: Note that these only work with OP's sample. As soon as those `/PATTERN/,+N` ranges overlap these solutions will be off - the only one that works with arbitrary input in this case is the awk one-liner suggested by @ctac_ A simple range address is not enough to do this properly (so as to handle arbitrary input) with `sed`. Depending on the value of `N` [it can get rather complicated](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/213402/22142)...

Comment: This answer is much more concise than any of the answers on the answers on the "duplicate". You may want to add this answer over there as well.